# EM waves from AC current in a loop?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, antennas

The video [How does an Antenna work?](https://youtu.be/ZaXm6wau-jc?t=33) shows a loop of wire and says it can't be used as an antenna.

[image]

I am confused because I thought electrons under AC current could be considered as accelerating charges and that any accelerating charge produces EM waves. So which is right ?

NB: Yes I read the similar but slightly different question: [Does AC current produce EM waves?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/93507/does-ac-current-produce-em-waves)

Comment: What is the blue brick in the middle of the loop? (I'm not going to watch a video to understand your question, so please include all relevant information in your question post)

Comment: @ThePhoton please ignore the blue brick and the black lines coming out of it.

Comment: @ThePhoton i edited the vid link so that it starts right on the single loop animation

Comment: Looking a bit more at the video, I think he's just wrong. He seems to think that only electric dipole antennas can transmit a signal. But [loop antennas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_antenna) are well known and widely used. They aren't used much for transmission, but by the reciprocity principle any receiving antenna can also in principle be used as a transmitting antenna. Some of the reasons they're more practical for receiving are discussed in the Wiki article.

Comment: @ThePhoton I checked for loop antennas initially but it seems they arent really a loop, the circle seems to always be cut on top and replaced by a capacitance. The french wiki shows technical drawings (unlike the english one)

Comment: I don't know enough French to understand the French Wiki page. But the English one shows photos of several examples of loop antennas with no capacitor in the loop (possibly there are capacitors near the feed point for impedance matching reasons).

Comment: Although accelerating point charges radiate, an infinite number of them moving in a circle (and uniformly distributed around that circle) do not. Their radiative fields cancel each other out. This is sometimes a homework exercise in a graduate-level course on electromagnetism.

Comment: @G.Smith could you detail your answer or provide a link to the solution of such problem ?

Comment: @ManudeHanoi https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/463e/3ef7f89d34c7a1205f3481ff17ad2a54fd55.pdf

Comment: @G.Smith wow math hell ! :D Do you think this extends to AC current though ?

Comment: @ManudeHanoi I don’t think an AC current in a circular loop would radiate. I’m less sure about that, bit it seems likely that the radiative fields would still cancel. The other argument for no radiation is that for a circular loop the dipole, octupole, quadrupole, etc. moments are zero.