# Induced current when electromagnetic wave meets wire loop plane perpendicular to wave

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

I was interested in electromagnetic induction in loops, since ground loops and such tend to be a problem in electronic system engineering. To me, it seems like induction in loops may tend to cancel out. For example, if the plane of a simple wire loop (that is just a ring of wire and nothing else) is perpendicular to an electromagnetic wave, using the normal rules for induction in wires, the E-field of the electromagnetic wave would be parallel to the top and bottom of the loop, and induce a current in the same direction in both the top and bottom. The sides, would be perpendicular to the E-field, and have no electromotive force on them. I asked about this on Quora, and was told that a "counterclockwise circulation" would be induced per Lenz's law. I know inserting a north pole into a wire loop does that, but, that was not what I asked.

I found this question here on Physics Stack Exchange, [EM waves from AC current in a loop?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/490880/em-waves-from-ac-current-in-a-loop), and it seems to suggest cancellation of forces for a radiating wire loop. A receiving wire loop seems like it might have similar behaviour.

So my question is, what current is induced in a wire loop whose plane is perpendicular to an electromagnetic wave, when the electromagnetic wave passes over it.

Comment: Do you assume anything about how the loop size compares to the wavelength? For a small loop (much smaller than a wavelength), the magnetic field needs to have a component perpendicular to the loop surface for a substantial current to be induced, this doesn't happen in the scenario you describe. For a loop comparable in size to a wavelength, there can be current induced: note that the current has spatial variation and in general currents can flow in the same direction on opposite sides of the loop (like a folded dipole antenna). See polarization and radiation patterns of resonant loop antennas.

Comment: H-field perpendicular to loop surface seems to fit with my understanding of what is needed. Much the same as for any receiving antenna. The wire loop then needs to face EM wave with its side. Good point about spatial variation. OK folded dipole antenna has current induced in same directions? This text says that too, https://www.waves.utoronto.ca/prof/svhum/ece422/notes/13-folded.pdf. Interesting!

Comment: Since I was mostly interested in understanding the issue of ground loops of loops in circuits from EMI/EMC perspective, do ground loops tend to have a behaviour similar to folded dipoles, and get current induced in same direction on opposite sides? That would clear up any confusion I have about them.

Comment: Yes, at resonance the folded dipole has the current flowing in the same direction in both wires, like that document indicates as "antenna mode". Resonant loop antennas generally work the same way. As for ground loops, sure, if the wavelength (i.e. frequency) is right, a ground loop could act like a folded dipole antenna. If you have more specific questions about ground loops, you might get more helpful answers at [Amateur Radio SE](https://ham.stackexchange.com) or [EE SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks! Mostly I wanted to clear up the induced current in same direction thing, since that is what I predicted would happen but I did not know it could actually receive that way. Am aware ground loops have other issues as well beside as antenna. Have lots more to learn about them as antenna, probably, Amateur Radio SE sounds like a good place to ask about that. Thanks for helping me clear up the direction issue!